# JavaScript implementation of Math.pow

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, recursion

I implemented Math.pow using a log(n) solution just like this article on geeksforgeeks

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/

However, I'm finding that the function does not exit its base case as I had intended. This program seems like it works in C but not JS.

Therefore, I am concluding that there is something about C that I am assuming works as well in JavaScript.

What am I missing in my JavaScript implementation?

***Be forewarned:*** the codesnippet as it is will have a max call stack exceeded error

```js
var myPow = function(x, n) {
  var res = 1
  var temp;
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  temp = myPow(x, n / 2)
  if (n % 2 === 0) {
    return temp * temp
  } else {
    return x * temp * temp
  }
};

console.log(myPow(2,3));
```

Comment: `console.log(n)` and you will see the problem

Comment: @Anthony :hope to  find it useful ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38666376/747579

Comment: Your recursive call isn't in tail position. Here's a tail recursive ES2015 solution: `const power = (base, exp, acc = 1) => exp === 0 ? acc : power(base, exp - 1, base * acc)`.

Comment: Take a look at iterative (non recursive) approaches on integer math for some additional ideas: [Power by squaring for negative exponents](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Brief :

use `parseInt` or `Math.floor` to have `y/2` as integer, unleness you will not reach `0` which is the stopper of **recursion** .

---

## Details

if you want to transalte  **[C Algo]**:

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (y%2 == 0)
        return power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);
    else
        return x*power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);
 
}
```

To **[JS Algo]** , you will have :

```
function power(x,y){
     if(y===0){return 1}
     else if (y%2 ===0){
         return power(x,parseInt(y/2))*power(x,parseInt(y/2))
     }else{
          return x*power(x,parseInt(y/2))*power(x,parseInt(y/2))
     }

}
```

---

## DEMO  :

```js
    function power(x,y){
         if(y===0){return 1}
         else if (y%2 ===0){
             return power(x,parseInt(y/2))*power(x,parseInt(y/2))
         }else{
              return x*power(x,parseInt(y/2))*power(x,parseInt(y/2))
         }
    
    }


console.log(power(3,2))
```

Comment: While this is generally safe, it's standard best practice to always provide the radix for parseInt: `parseInt(y/2, 10)`

Comment: `parseInt()` parses a string and returns an integer. You should be using [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) instead to truncate the decimal places

Comment: @Andreas &@rgthree : THank u ,, any way , the idea is to reach `0` at the end of recursion to Avoid `Infinity`

Comment: Note that bitwise or `|` with 0 also works: `2.3434 | 0 === 2`

Comment: Nice job! any idea on how you would have this work with negative exponentiation as well?

Comment: You shouldn't misuse `parseInt` to perform a `floor` operation. That wouldn't work on larger numbers. E.g., `parseInt(1000000000000000000000000/2)` is `5`.

Comment: To make it more simpler, power(x, parseInt(y/ 2)) can be stored and accessed instead of calling it again. Still, a great example !

Comment: @AnthonyChung .

Comment: Is there any way to implement this using javascript reducers?

Comment: The question is requesting to translate the code from programming language to another. Otherwise, I totally agree with you to use reducers.

Comment: ok, so from when 3^-2 is 9.

Comment: It's incorrect.
Try to test with this.

pow(3,2/5) => return 3

But actually Math.pow(3,2/5) => return 1.5518455739153598

Answer (score 2):

### **Try this out**

It will give you the same result of JavaScript build in method ( Math.pi(x, y)) but the only problem is you can't use Power as decimal number.

```js
Math.my_pow = (x, y) => {
  if (typeof x != "number" || typeof y != "number")
    throw "(x) and (y) should only be number";

  if (y == 0) return 1;
  if (x == 0 && y > 0 ) return 0;

  const base = x;
  var value = base;
  var pow = y;
  if (y < 0) pow = y * -1;

  for (var i = 1; i < pow; i++) {
    value *= base;
  }

  if (y < 0) return 1 / value;
  return value;
};

try {
  console.log( Math.my_pow(0, -3) );
  console.log( Math.pow(0, -2) );

  console.log( Math.my_pow(-5, -3) );
  console.log( Math.pow(-5, -3) );

  console.log( Math.my_pow(8, -7) );
  console.log( Math.pow(8, -7)) ;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: definitely more readable than the accepted recursive solution.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a little bit from @Abdennour's answer

```js
function power(x, y) {
    if (y === 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    var yBy2 = y / 2;
    var pow = power(x, parseInt( yBy2, 10) );
    if (y % 2 === 0) {
      return pow * pow;
    } else {
      return x * pow * pow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

*** Simple Logic ***

```
function pow (p,y){
    if(p > 0 && y === 0){
        return 1;
    }
    x = p;
    while(y > 1){
        x = p*x;
        y--;
    }
    return x;
}


console.log(pow(0,0)+'\n'); // 0
console.log(pow(2,4)+'\n'); // 16
console.log(pow(2,0)+'\n'); // 1
console.log(pow(0,2)+'\n'); // 0
```

Comment: We cannot handle negative power in this solution.