# Numerical approximation of 2^x

Tags: algorithm, math, pseudocode

I'm programming a library for arbitrary precision arithmetic. The last problem I'm facing is the power function. I figured out to compute `2 ^ (y log2(x))` instead of `x ^ y` and there remains a single subproblem: How can I efficiently compute `2 ^ x` with `x` in the range `(0,1)` (zero and one excluded).

Since I obviously store rationals anyway, `x` has the form `p/q` (`p < q`). Therefore I could calculate the `q`-th root of `2` (Wikipedia's n-th root algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm) and then exponentiate the result by `p`.

However, this seems very inefficient. Is there any superior algorithm? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you think more about it you will find why the natural logarithm is called natural. It does not make much sense to base everything on the 2. `exp(y*ln(x))` has less constants. -- Study [bc libmath](http://www.rkeene.org/viewer/devel/old/bc-dos/bc/libmath.b.htm) for a proven implementation of these functions.

Comment: see [Power by squaring for negative exponents](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) for the basics and then the sublinks for more advanced stuff  especially the `fixed point bignum pow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `2 ^ x = e ^ (x ln 2)` and `e ^ x = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + ...` this might be a way to go. The series expansion for `e ^ x`converges quickly for limited x (as in your case).

Comment: If x is still too large for quick convergence of the series the identity e^x = (e^(x/2))^2 can be used a few times.

Comment: O(n) convergence for this Taylor series.  You'll need a lot of terms for double precision accuracy.

Comment: @duffymo for `x = ln 2 = 0.69...` (the maximal value requested by the OP) and double precision the last term needed is `x^15/15!` since `x^16/16! = 1.3..E-16 < 1/2^52`.

Comment: @coproc: The question was for "arbitrary precision arithmetic".

Comment: @coproc - Yes, that's how O(n) works.  One term for each digit of precision.  Infinite precision is not practical.

Comment: @LutzL the title of the question is "Numerical approximation ..."