# Is there any way to compute 1.01^x without loops, using only integer add, mul, sub, div, exp?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

Is there any way to implement the `Uint256 -> Uint256` function `f(x) = floor(1.01 ^ x)`, using only a constant number of operations `add`, `mul`, `sub`, `div`, `exp`, all of those can only operate on integer numbers?

Comment: But what do you want to do about the floating point component of the output, if there is one (quite likely)?  I think an ALU is basically what a computer would use to compute an exponent, so this is a known problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen floor it out (I edited the OP). Makes sense that this is a known problem, I'd appreciate some reference.

Comment: Not sure I see how that helps, that algorithm seems to use floats...

Comment: I upvoted your question, I hope you get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you!

Comment: Squaring could still work by using `101` as the base and reducing the intermediate results by factors of 100 any time they get too large. The trick would be to balance this so that no precision is lost in the last digits.

Comment: Do you have to be able to handle the whole int256 range without overflowing i.e. if the result can fit in a int256 then you must be able to calculate it using only these operations and only using int256 variables? FWIW, a lookup table for this would need 17833 entries

Comment: Stupid question: is `Int256` the type that takes values in `[0..255]`, or the type that uses 256 bits to represent an integer? Or something else?

Comment: and also it is signed or not? and standard two's complement in case of yes? In case of 256 bits I see no point of not using loops unless you want to implement this directly with silicon instead of program

Comment: @AakashM 256 bits!

Comment: @Spektre not signed!! actually. Point of not using loops is that I need to run it in a VM which charges real money for each executed arithmetic operation.

Comment: @samgak I think it is OK if it works for just `Uint64` (or perhaps smaller if that is still too big) inputs/outputs since I won't be using more than that. It is able to use `Uint256` numbers in intermediate computations, as that is the native word size.

Comment: What is `exp`? It can't be the normal exponential function, as that is not integer-to-integer.

Comment: 256 bit, OK. I'm thinking lookup table, as @samgak says, since the function you are actually interested in is `[0..17833] -> UInt256`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Newton's binomial series

```
(1+h)^x = 1+x*h + x*(x-1)/2*h^2 + x*(x-1)*(x-2)/6*h^3 + ...
        = 1 + x*h*(1+(x-1)*h/2*(1+(x-2)*h/3*(1+...)))
```

To get a terminating computation, one would first have to reduce `x`, I'd think by multiples of `log(2)/log(1.01)`.

Essentially, in the intermediate result you have to use some kind of fixed point arithmetics.

Comment: the op's question says that it can only operate on integer numbers. so is it permitted to do `x*h` since h=0.01  ?

Comment: Dividing by 100 is allowed.

Comment: oh maybe i got it

Comment: Integer rounding is at the moment not the primary problem. Convergence is, i.e., that a small number of terms provide a sufficiently accurate result. No ideas on that.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get your answer at first and I assumed your edit meant that it wouldn't work. I even asked a similar question later on. It works fine, though. Thanks.

Comment: @LutzL what is a good choice for the limit of recursions, though?

Answer (score 1):

I would try fixed point. Let assume your `Int256` is unsigned 8 bit int then try `8.8` or `8.16` or `8.32` fixed format. Depends on what precision you need.

let rewrite the number to `a.b` format and assume `8.16` (`8.8` ignores too much of the `1.01` binary ones to my taste) so you got:

```
1.01^x = (1+0.01*65536/65536)^x = (1+655/65536)^x
a=1
b=655
```

now just compute integer `pow` for example with power by squaring see:

- [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214)

The result then convert back to integer so either

- `floor` (use just `a`)
- `round` (increment `a` if `b>32767` )

To avoid loops just encode the power by squaring into few copy paste lines (one for each bit).

btw this can be done with `+,<<` if you realize you are multiplying by:

```
1.01dec = 1.0000001010001111 bin
```

So you just can do `shift` and `add` for each binary `1` instead of `mul` in case `mul` is a problem ...