# find greatest number, x for given y and n such that x ^ y <= n

Tags: algorithm, math, bitset

I need to find a greatest number, x for given y and n such that x ^ y <= n

Here n can be very large number - 1 <= n <= 10^10
and 1 <= y <= 10^5

```
for example : 

for y = 5 and n = 1024
x ^ 5, then x = 4 (4 ^ 5 = 1024)

for y = 5 and n = 480
x ^ 5 , then x = 3 (3 ^ 5 = 243, 4 ^ 5 = 1024) - selecting lowest one, so x = 3
```

i have written a small program, But i want more efficient technique because n and y can be very large.

```
def get(y, n):

    x = 1
    while x ** y <= n:
        x += 1
    return x - 1
```

Comment: With some simple arithmetic: `x^y==n => x=n^(1/y)` (i.e. the `y`-th root of n, assuming `x` and `n` to be positive). Round down to find the greatest integer `x`.

Comment: (Continuing from previous comment) ... and since the desired values for `x` go up to only 10^10, if `x` is an integer the double floating point type has enough precision to guarantee the correct answer.

Comment: Why is bitset tagged? Is there some plan to use it?

Comment: @NicoSchertler n and y can be very large so that formula will take huge time

Comment: @Atul I added edit1 to my answer with what I had in mind + the bin search explanation. btw `10^10` is not large ...

Answer (score 2):

Using a multiple-precision arithmetic library, such as gmpy2's `iroot`.

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> root, exact = gmpy2.iroot(n, y)
```

This is simply an integer n-th root algorithm.  It should be fast and correct even for huge numbers (something that floats cannot guarantee in the general case).

The second value returned is a boolean which indicates if the root is exact or not.

```
>>> print(*gmpy2.iroot(1024, 5))
4 True
>>> print(*gmpy2.iroot(480, 5))
3 False
```

Comment: i cannot use external libraries.

Comment: @Atul in that case use bin search or `pow -> log2/exp2` approach as My answer suggest in the linked answer you will find also C++ examples see especially bullet **#5**

Comment: Sure you can.  You just pip install it.

Comment: @Spektre can you explain more on how do i solve it using binary search

Answer (score 0):

you can use binary search on integer to move from your `O(x)` to `O(log(x))` if you apply floating math then:

```
x^y = n  // ^(1/y)
x = n^1/y
x = floor(pow(n,1/y))
```

your example `n=400` and `y=5` is like this:

```
x = floor(pow(400,1/5))
x = floor(pow(400,0.2))
x = floor(3.3144540173399868004685801443126)
x = 3
```

of coarse for big `n` will this not work with basic floating types. In such case either use bin search on big integers or implement your own bigint pow if you do not have it already at your disposal. Anyway both approaches are described here:

- [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) do not get fouled by the title it is all integer math ...

**[edit1]**

after absorbing your comments:

```
n = < 1 , 10^10 >
y = < 1 , 10^5 >
no FPU just integer math
```

I would use binary search. You need to use at least `ceil(log2(10^10))=34 bit` variables for this so unsigned 64 bit `QWORD` it is. if you do not have such variables you need to implement it from lower bit width variables first.

The binary search mask will be:

```
m = 2^33 = 1<<33 = 0x0000000200000000
```

so you first need to implement `pow` and then `root` adapting code from linked answer here is **C++** result:

```cpp
#define T_bits 34
#define T_MSB  0x0000000200000000
#define T      QWORD

T pow(T x,T y)  // power by squaring returns z=x^y where x>=0, y>=0
    {
    T i,z=1;
    for (i=0;i<T_bits;i++)  // test all bits from MSB to LSB
        {
        z*=z;
        if (T(y&T_MSB)) z*=x;
        y<<=1;
        }
    return z;
    }
T bits(T x) // count how many bits is in x
    {
    T m=T_MSB,z=T_bits;
    for (;m;m>>=1,z--)
     if (x>=m) break;
    return z;
    }
T root(T x,T y) // bin search y-th root returns z=x^(1/y)
    {
    T m,z;
    m=((bits(x)+y-1)/y);        // ceil(bits(x)/y)
    if (m) m=1<<m; else m=1;    // MSB of the result for bin search 2^(ceil(bits(x)/y))
    for (z=0;m;m>>=1)           // test all bits of x from MSB to LSB
        {
        z|=m;                   // set actual bit
        if (pow(z,y)>x) z^=m;   // clear if result exceedes x
        }
    return z;
    }
```

for those of you that have just 32 bit arithmetics and have lover limit `n<2^32` change the defines to:

```cpp
#define T_bits 32
#define T_MSB  0x80000000
#define T      DWORD
```

or use any other variable type you got at your disposal. The `T` is your data-type `T_MSB` is MSB bit set and `T_bits` is used bit count.

If you use:

```
root(400,5);
```

it will return `3`. You can use your `**` instead of `pow` I can not as my compiler does not recognize `**` operator. Now to explanation of **binary search**

let assume your example. You start with `x=1` then test `x=2` then `x=3` and so on until you cross `x^y>=n` so in reality you had checked `pow(n,1/y)` values. if we use `n=10000, y=2` that will lead to `100` tests.

The binary search does not increment but set individual bits instead. `10000` has 14 bits so `ceil(14/y)=7` so the process will be:

```
x with set bit|  x^y  | action
-------------------------------
0100 0000 bin |  4096 | none
0110 0000 bin |  9216 | none
0111 0000 bin | 12544 | clear
0110 1000 bin | 10816 | clear
0110 0100 bin | 10000 | none
0110 0010 bin | 10404 | clear
0110 0001 bin | 10201 | clear
-------------------------------
0110 0000 bin | 10000 | result
```

leading to only `7` tests instead of your naive `100`.