# Calculating power of huge numbers in less time

Tags: c#, math, biginteger

I want to calculate the power of huge number using C#

I've used this code.
it works but I want to calculate it in less time.

```
BigInteger a;
a = Math.Pow(4100000000,4100000000);
Console.Writeline(a);
```

Comment: Can you share the current time?

Comment: Is your exponent an integer number (doesn't have a decimal point)?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but more than 2 hours.

Comment: Yes it is an integer.

Comment: 1. Not a C# coder but Are you sure `Math.Pow(4100000000,4100000000)` is computed on BigIntegers? 2. The result of your operation is `~130925204732` bits long. The floating `pow` is using `log,exp` functions and I would expect that is way slower than the Integer power by squaring on such big numbers. See [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) Anyway You would need a lot of big multiplications so even with [Schönhage-Strassen fsqr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214) it will take time so 2hr looks reasonable.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, so we have to guess your meaning. Please edit your question to correct this.

Comment: I think there is no optimization for this problem.

Comment: @Guufulltun such big numbers powered are usually taken in some modulo arithmetics that is way faster (see `modpow` in the NTT implementation from the `fsqr` link). I see no practically real use for the full value anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can test this but not sure if this is faster than the native function `Math.Pow`

```
using System; 

public class GFG{ 

    static float power(float x, int y) 
    { 
        float temp; 

        if( y == 0) 
            return 1; 
        temp = power(x, y/2);  

        if (y % 2 == 0) 
            return temp * temp; 
        else
        { 
            if(y > 0) 
                return x * temp * temp; 
            else
                return (temp * temp) / x; 
        } 
    }  

    // Program to test function power  
    public static void Main() 
    { 
        float x = 2; 
        int y = -3; 

        Console.Write(power(x, y));

        float x = 4100000000; 
        int y = 4100000000; 

        Console.Write(power(x, y)); 

    } 
}
```

> Time Complexity: O(logn)
>
> Space Complexity: O(1)
>
> Algorithmic Paradigm: Divide and conquer.

Comment: float doesn't give a good result when the result is a very big number.

Comment: Math.Pow take 3 seconds and Power take 5 seconds when I tried with 100000^100000