# Why is this code bad to calculate the power (less efficient)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

```
class Solution {
   public:
      double myPow(double x, int n) {
         double result=1;
         bool neg=false;

         if(n<0)
         {
            n = -1*n;
            neg=true;
         }
         for(int i =1; i<=n;i++)
         {
            result = x*result;
         }  
         if(neg)
         {
            result = 1/result;
         }
         return result;
      }

};
```

Comment: It requires `n` multiplications there are faster algorithms

Comment: You might do something like `pow(x, 4)` -> `pow(pow(x, 2), 2)`, instead of `x * x * x * x`.

Comment: Well it's definitely slower than the standard `pow`

Comment: Also in C++ you can have stand-alone functions in addition to methods

Comment: This is a faster technique https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring for non-negative `n` (and recasting the problem for the negative n case is trivial). Writing `pow(x, n)` as `exp(n log x)` might be faster too, but check for floating point naughties.

Comment: It seems a template from puzzle site.

Comment: @Jarod42 I would rephrase - `pow(x, n) = pow(x, n/2)^2` for even `n`s...multiply by `x` for odd ones.

Comment: in addition to what has been said already, your code is bad, because you are reinventing the wheel. `std::pow` does what you need and unless you have a good reason to write your own you shouldnt (though I guess having this as a homework task is reason enough ;).

Comment: if you want to put it in a class then at least declare the method as `static`, currently one needs to create an instance for no gain

Comment: see [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) there are more options how to calculate each of which is faster than yours ... using better complexities ...

Answer (score 8):

Your method uses `O(N)` operations to compute the power.
It is possible to compute the power in `O(log(N))` operations.

For that reason, it is not the most efficient.

The logic for converting it to `O(log(N))` operations can be seen at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring.

The core idea is that

[image]

To make this logic work, you need to move the code that computes the power to a positive value to its own function, which can be recursive.

```
      double myPowPositive(double x, int n) {
         // Use the efficient algorithm.
      }

      double myPow(double x, int n) {
         double result=1;
         bool neg=false;

         if(n<0)
         {
            n = -1*n;
            neg=true;
         }

         result = myPowPositive(x, n);

         if(neg)
         {
            result = 1/result;
         }
         return result;
      }
```

Comment: Not for negative n though?

Comment: @Bathsheba, the OP computes the power to a positve value first, and then does `1/result`.

Comment: Indeed, but one needs to point out these trivialities. Have an upvote all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not providing code, because this is clearly a homework question, but I hope to guide you towards the correct solution.

The problem is that the core for loop requires `n` multiplications.  The usual way of doing this is to loop through the bits in `n`, multiplying by `x` if the bit is set, and squaring `x` each time you move on to the next bit.  This requires O(ceil(lg(n))) multiplications.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot really stop the loss of precision in a denominator unless you know its prime factors. This is why it is not a good choice to try this exercise for a denominator (negative exponents), but to try it for numerators (positive exponents) first.