# Is there something like that Math.Pow() method but extremely precise as in at least 50 or a hundred digits?

Tags: c#, math

If i try using Math.Pow in a decimal variable i wont be allowed to do so because it needs to be a double. Is there any way i can print extremely precise powers? Extremely as in at least 50 or a hundred digits

Comment: Those dup targets have nothing at all to say about the crux of the question, namely arithmetic of higher precision than is available using standard C# arithmetic types.

Comment: Octavylon, it might help if you explained what you need this extreme precision for. Are you working with integers only, or with floating point numbers of arbitrary precision?

Comment: 64 bit `double` can store `~17` digits so if you want `50` digits you need higher precision arithmetics (at least `ceil(50/log10(2)) =167` bits of mantisa however depending on the algorithm you might need a multiple of it). google `BigDecimal,BigInteger`  ... If you want to encode this your self see [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214)