# Is there any way to find value of log 3 (base) 5 (exponent)?

Tags: math, logarithm

When finding the value of log 3 (base) 5 (exponent)

Is it common to use common log / common log ?

If there is another way, please let me know.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Change of base formula]

You can use common log / common log.

Answer (score 1):

yes its common to use

```
logb(a) = log(a)/log(b)
```

If you do not have `log` then you can compute it using binary search `x` in `b^x <= a` where `x <= logb(a)`

there are also other ways for example you can use some kind of series like Taylor, Chebychev or some math identity or fit with curve etc.

Algorithm depends also on targeted domain and also on computing environment. I recommend to see:

- [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214)

especially the links at the end ...